# Get files name in directory

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using this code to get all files in directory. But with this code I get file name and directory path. Can you help me to fix the code only to return List of Files names without file path.

```
public List<String> getAllDirFiles() {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream
            = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("repository"))) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            fileNames.add(path.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    return fileNames;
}
```

Comment: Read the manual. Hint: `File.isDirectory()`

Comment: @Unihedron You did not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @Joiner I advised reading the manual and that it's related to `.isDirectory()`, so while my comment didn't answer the question, it wasn't obsolete either.

Comment: Yes, see the answers.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you've solved your problem, please share it with us by using `Add an Answer` button if it's not already there. __[Accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)__ to indicate the best answer or a working solution that helped you the most (and close the question), and [upvote answers which were helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 3):

This code will return exactly the list of filenames that are located in the directory named "repository". I specially used the Java Streaming API as the tag of question is java-8

```
List<String> fileNames = Files.list(Paths.get("repository"))
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(Path::getFileName)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you add more information about what this does? Or an explanation.

Comment: Roughly, `Files.list` return a stream of `Path` entries, on which a filter is applied to reduce the list to regular files, then we get the filename, and then the filename as String (`Object::toString`), and the we collect all into a list. You can read more about stream here: http://www.journaldev.com/2774/java-8-stream-api-example-tutorial (or using DuckDuckGo and `java tutorial 8 Stream` keywords).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `path.toString()`, use `path.getFileName().toString()`

Comment: You did not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @Joiner without deep Java knowledge, I still beg to differ.

Comment: @FelixFrank What do you mean?

Comment: @Joiner I believe that the change proposed through the answer will solve the issue that's being asked.